# dataframe style gradient shading based on another dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to base off gradient shading of a dataframe, using values from another dataframe (same dimension).

I have the below code, based from an answer to a similar question. **However I need the shading to have the effect of "axis=None", where as below applies a column-wise shade.**

```
A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c']) 
B = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
from matplotlib import colors

def b_g(s, cmap='PuBu', low=0, high=0):
    # Pass the columns from Dataframe A 
    a = A.loc[:,s.name].copy()
    rng = a.max() - a.min()
    norm = colors.Normalize(a.min() - (rng * low),
                        a.max() + (rng * high))
    normed = norm(a.values)
    c = [colors.rgb2hex(x) for x in plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap)(normed)]
    return ['background-color: %s' % color for color in c]

B.style.apply(b_g,cmap='PuBu')
```